# Tailwindcss @apply directive doesn't work inside vue component

Tags: vuejs2, laravel-8, tailwind-css, laravel-jetstream, inertiajs

I create a laravel application with jetstream and inertia-vue stack for my new project problem is `Tailwindcs` version 2 using `postCss` and it doesn't support `@apply` directive inside vue components but inside `.css` file it works fine I don't want that because that css file will load my every page I just want short inline utility classes with `@apply` directive but I can't, How Can I achieve that.?

#### inside my vue template

```html
<template>
 <div class="mt-4">
  <label for="hello">Hello</label>
  <input id="hello" class="input"/>
 </div>
</templete>

<style scoped>
    .input {
        @apply bg-gray-200 border h-10
    }
</style>
```

output inside browser like this

[image]

webpack.mix.js

```js
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js').vue()
    .postCss('resources/css/app.css', 'public/css', [
        require('postcss-import'),
        require('tailwindcss'),
        require('autoprefixer'),
    ])
    .webpackConfig(require('./webpack.config'));

if (mix.inProduction()) {
    mix.version();
}
```

webpack.config.js

```js
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            '@': path.resolve('resources/js'),
        },
    },
};
```

```html
tailwind version : "^2.0.1",
laravel version : 8.x,
jetstream version : 2.x,
inertiajs version: "^0.8.2"
```

Comment: Could this be related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65158139/1870780?

Comment: Nope I tried that, not work for me.

Answer (score 20):

You have to set the `lang="postcss"` attribute on the `<style>` tag as Tailwind is a PostCSS plugin.

So change this

```
<style scoped>
    .input {
        @apply bg-gray-200 border h-10
    }
</style>
```

To this

```
<style lang="postcss" scoped>
    .input {
        @apply bg-gray-200 border h-10
    }
</style>
```

Comment: using this approach results in follwing error :

`Module parse failed: Unexpected token (19:0)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
| 
| 
> .btn{
|     color :white;
| }`

Any ideas ?

Comment: @BartMommens A quick Google search resulted in this - https://github.com/tailwindlabs/discuss/issues/452

Comment: thanks for the link. i've came across a lot of different solutions for this issue. none seemed to work properly after the upgrade from jetstream 1x to 2x. Ended up removing all the @ apply from scoped styling in vue components and putting everything in separate stylesheet. No errors anymore ...

Answer (score 1):

A workaround that can temporarily solve this problem:

.

In `webpack.config.js`

```
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': path.resolve('resources/js')
    }
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(postcss)$/,
        use: [
          'vue-style-loader',
          { loader: 'css-loader', options: { importLoaders: 1 } },
          'postcss-loader'
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

.

In `postcss.config.js` (if this file not exist, just create it)

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    require('postcss-import'),
    require('tailwindcss')('./tailwind.config.js'),
    require('autoprefixer')
  ]
}
```

.

Now you can use in Vue file by adding `lang="postcss`

```
<style lang="postcss">
.input-form {
  @apply block w-full mt-1 border-gray-300 rounded-md shadow-sm focus:border-indigo-300 focus:ring focus:ring-indigo-200 focus:ring-opacity-50;
}
</style>
```

.

This answer is based on the discussion here: https://github.com/laravel-mix/laravel-mix/issues/2778#issuecomment-826121931

Comment: for me I needed to remove the `land="postcss"` inside the vue style in order for it to work.

Answer (score 1):

Creating postcss.config.js & adding the below snippet worked for me:

```
module.exports = {
    plugins: {
        tailwindcss: {},
        autoprefixer: {},
    },
}
```